Cannot play music using wavelink in discord.py
so I am trying to make a Discord Music bot with Wavelink and Lavalink but it is not working, whenever I run the play command it says "Added to Queue" and "Now Playing" but it doesn't actually play anything. I'm running an example code provided by Wavelink and I also have a Lavalink server set up which works fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm pretty new to Wavelink and Lavalink so I don't know about a lot of stuff going on here and the docs has nothing about this. I can't tell if the issue is the code or the server.
Here's the full code:
TOKEN = "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"

import asyncio
import logging
from typing import cast

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import wavelink


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents: discord.Intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True

        discord.utils.setup_logging(level=logging.INFO)
        super().__init__(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        nodes = [wavelink.Node(uri="your_uri_here", password="your_password_here")]

        # cache_capacity is EXPERIMENTAL. Turn it off by passing None
        await wavelink.Pool.connect(nodes=nodes, client=self, cache_capacity=100)

    async def on_ready(self) -> None:
        logging.info("Logged in: %s | %s", self.user, self.user.id)

    async def on_wavelink_node_ready(self, payload: wavelink.NodeReadyEventPayload) -> None:
        logging.info("Wavelink Node connected: %r | Resumed: %s", payload.node, payload.resumed)

    async def on_wavelink_track_start(self, payload: wavelink.TrackStartEventPayload) -> None:
    # Payload original is the "original" track that was added to the queue, with all custom attributes we set.

        if payload.original:
            await payload.original.ctx.send(f'Now playing: {payload.original}.')

bot: Bot = Bot()


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx: commands.Context, *, query: str) -> None:
    vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)

    # Retrieve existing player on guild.
    vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client


    tracks: wavelink.Search = await wavelink.Playable.search(query)
    if not tracks:
        await ctx.send("No tracks found...")
        return

    if isinstance(tracks, wavelink.Playlist):
        tracks.track_extras(ctx=ctx)
        added: int = await vc.queue.put_wait(tracks)
        await ctx.send(f'Added {added} tracks from the playlist {tracks.name} to the queue.')

    else:
        track: wavelink.Playable = tracks[0]
        track.ctx = ctx

        await vc.queue.put_wait(track)
        await ctx.send(f'Added {track} to the queue.')


    if not vc.current:
        await vc.play(vc.queue.get())



@bot.command(name="toggle", aliases=["pause", "resume"])
async def pause_resume(ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    """Pause or Resume the Player depending on its current state."""
    player: wavelink.Player = cast(wavelink.Player, ctx.voice_client)
    if not player:
        return

    await player.pause(not player.paused)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("\u2705")


@bot.command()
async def volume(ctx: commands.Context, value: int) -> None:
    """Change the volume of the player."""
    player: wavelink.Player = cast(wavelink.Player, ctx.voice_client)
    if not player:
        return

    await player.set_volume(value)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("\u2705")


@bot.command(aliases=["dc"])
async def disconnect(ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    """Disconnect the Player."""
    player: wavelink.Player = cast(wavelink.Player, ctx.voice_client)
    if not player:
        return

    await player.disconnect()
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("\u2705")


async def main() -> None:
    async with bot:
        await bot.start(TOKEN)


asyncio.run(main())

Lavalink logs:
2024-04-27T12:06:20.830+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-27T12:06:23.418+06:00  WARN 11324 --- [           main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2024-04-27T12:06:23.630+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-27T12:06:23.635+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2775 ms
2024-04-27T12:06:24.280+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] c.s.d.l.tools.GarbageCollectionMonitor   : GC monitoring enabled, reporting results every 2 minutes.
2024-04-27T12:06:26.926+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] l.server.config.KoeConfiguration         : OS: WINDOWS, Arch: X86_64
2024-04-27T12:06:26.931+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] l.server.config.KoeConfiguration         : Enabling JDA-NAS
2024-04-27T12:06:26.941+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] c.s.l.c.natives.NativeLibraryLoader      : Native library udpqueue: loading with filter null
2024-04-27T12:06:26.950+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] c.s.l.c.natives.NativeLibraryLoader      : Native library udpqueue: successfully loaded.
2024-04-27T12:06:27.111+06:00  WARN 11324 --- [           main] l.server.config.SentryConfiguration      : Turning off sentry
2024-04-27T12:06:27.960+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] io.undertow                              : starting server: Undertow - 2.3.6.Final
2024-04-27T12:06:28.076+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] org.xnio                                 : XNIO version 3.8.8.Final
2024-04-27T12:06:28.102+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] org.xnio.nio                             : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.8.Final
2024-04-27T12:06:28.402+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] org.jboss.threads                        : JBoss Threads version 3.5.0.Final
2024-04-27T12:06:28.541+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.undertow.UndertowWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 7000 (http)
2024-04-27T12:06:28.554+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : Started Launcher in 8.015 seconds (process running for 17.588)
2024-04-27T12:06:28.561+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [           main] lavalink.server.Launcher                 : Lavalink is ready to accept connections.
2024-04-27T12:07:00.051+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-04-27T12:07:00.051+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-04-27T12:07:00.066+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 15 ms
2024-04-27T12:07:00.129+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.HandshakeInterceptorImpl     : Incoming connection from /127.0.0.1:51735
2024-04-27T12:07:00.176+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /v4/websocket, client=127.0.0.1
2024-04-27T12:07:00.401+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] lavalink.server.io.SocketServer          : Connection successfully established from Wavelink/3.1.2
2024-04-27T12:07:01.188+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-3] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : PATCH /v4/sessions/btyh95wkwl500wp5, client=127.0.0.1, payload={"resuming": true, "timeout": 60}
2024-04-27T12:07:01.321+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /v4/info, client=127.0.0.1
2024-04-27T12:12:01.107+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : PATCH /v4/sessions/btyh95wkwl500wp5/players/1071307204868702429?noReplace=True, client=127.0.0.1, payload={"voice": {"sessionId": "a653b6cfd5f2ce5b60b45511656fbd49", "token": "6d8b1b4415991a56", "endpoint": "india2397.discord.media:443"}}
2024-04-27T12:12:02.379+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.player.AudioLoaderRestHandler   : Got request to load for identifier "ytmsearch:never gonna give you up"
2024-04-27T12:12:03.856+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] lavalink.server.player.AudioLoader       : Loaded playlist Search results for: never gonna give you up
2024-04-27T12:12:03.971+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /v4/loadtracks?identifier=ytmsearch:never%20gonna%20give%20you%20up, client=127.0.0.1
2024-04-27T12:12:04.632+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : PATCH /v4/sessions/btyh95wkwl500wp5/players/1071307204868702429?noReplace=False, client=127.0.0.1, payload={"track": {"encoded": "QAAA/gMAF05ldmVyIEdvbm5hIEdpdmUgWW91IFVwAAtSaWNrIEFzdGxleQAAAAAAA0PwAAtsWUJVYkJ1NFcwOAABACtodHRwczovL3d3dy55b3V0dWJlLmNvbS93YXRjaD92PWxZQlViQnU0VzA4AQB+aHR0cHM6Ly9saDMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tL2VDOURmUmNZU2s0RkUtZnZEQ0pTdV80eHNLZFZNS3h3bUZUWUZad1A4T3FCN1I0VEt4QWpLb1ItS3AxbFhlUmkyV2RkUEZZdWxTdGU0ZVctPXcxMDAwLWgxMDAwAAAHeW91dHViZQAAAAAAAAAA", "userData": {}}, "volume": 100, "position": 0, "endTime": null, "paused": false, "filters": {"equalizer": [{"band": 0, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 1, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 2, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 3, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 4, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 5, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 6, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 7, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 8, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 9, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 10, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 11, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 12, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 13, "gain": 0.0}, {"band": 14, "gain": 0.0}]}}
2024-04-27T12:12:04.657+06:00  WARN 11324 --- [back-1-thread-1] c.s.d.l.s.y.YoutubeAccessTokenTracker    : YouTube auth tokens can't be retrieved because email and password is not set in YoutubeAudioSourceManager, age restricted videos will throw exceptions.
2024-04-27T12:12:06.007+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [back-1-thread-1] c.s.d.l.s.y.YoutubeAccessTokenTracker    : Updating YouTube visitor id (current is null).
2024-04-27T12:12:06.497+06:00  INFO 11324 --- [back-1-thread-1] c.s.d.l.s.y.YoutubeAccessTokenTracker    : Updating YouTube visitor id succeeded, new one is Cgt1aWlRS2NEeUZNbyi4rrKxBjIKCgJCRBIEGgAgPDoMCAEgtPfv5YPnpZZm, next update will be after 600 seconds.

